# Decomposition of Correlated Jointly Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Here is a problem that I came across. Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(1,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ be two jointly gaussian random variables (with covariance $p$), and let $\overline{X} = X - 1$.

I am confused why we can say that $Y = p\overline{X} + (\sqrt{1 - p^2})Z$, where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is independent of $\overline{X}$. The solutions then proceed to justify this relation by ensuring that $\mathbb{E}[p\overline{X} + (\sqrt{1 - p^2})Z] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$, $\mathrm{var}(p\overline{X} + (\sqrt{1 - p^2})Z) = \mathrm{var}(Y)$, and $\mathrm{cov}(\overline{X}, p\overline{X} + (\sqrt{1 - p^2})Z) = \mathrm{cov}(\overline{X}, Y)$. I understand why we need to ensure the expectations and variances to be the same (to ensure it does have the same distribution), but why do we need to check whether the covariances are the same as well? And how does checking the covariances ensure that $Y = p\overline{X} + (\sqrt{1 - p^2})Z$, rather than just saying that they have the same distribution?

Answer (score 0):

For normal distributed random variables, correlated and independent are equivalent.  When computing the var(Y), cov(X-1,Z)=0 is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that $cov(X - 1, Z)$ need to be zero for them to be independent. My question is more towards why we can write $Y = p\overline{X} + \sqrt{1 - p^2}Z$.